# How do i write this amount of code into a PHP if statement?

Tags: php

How do i write an PHP `if` statement that says if this code

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from updates ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT 9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg_id=$row['update_time'];
$message=$row['item_content'];
?>

<?php echo $message; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

has the same output as a variable, then do nothing. I'm only asking because i dont know how to put this amount of code into an `if` statement. If anyone knows please post, thanks :)

Comment: Your question is confusing. What output are you trying to compare?

Comment: Also it is better to call the resultset `$result`, not `$sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing `$message` in each iteration build a `$messages` string to use in your if:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg_id=$row['update_time'];
$messages .= $row['item_content'];
}
if($messages != $old_messages) {
  // do something
}
```